# Sum values to certain amount

Tags: excel

[image]

My question is simple, though i don't know how to execute this task.  The spreadsheet that I'm using is sort of a timesheet, the picture is just a test sheet.  I would like to know, how can you allocate the amount of hours for each category into the limit of 10 ?
for example :

2 hours DT

6 hours OT

2 hours PPH

which makes up the 10 ?

Comment: I think you need to clarify what it is you are trying to do.  How do determine which row to use if it adds up to more than 10?

Comment: Thanx for the reply.  The limit of 10 is calculated like this.  =MIN(10,SUM(C4:I6)).  Now what I would like to know is, which of those individual hours per category, makes up the 10 hours ?  Hope my explanation makes sense ....

Comment: Not really.  In your example, it would appear that OT and PPH take "priority" over DT. What about OT vs PPH?  which of those should take priority over the other?

Comment: The priority shifts to which ever category has a hand in making the 10 hours full, almost like a loop function.  So if all 3 combined makes up the 10 hours, I would like to display the hours for each category that makes up the 10 hours.

Comment: I'm sorry but you are just not making sense. In your example, the spreadsheet  has 6 hours of OT, 6 hours of DT and 2 hours of PPH.  But in the space below it, you count 6 OT, only 2 of DT and 2 PPH.  You need to specify which ones should count and what should be omitted if the total goes _over_ 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you first need to calculate hours to date, check if that has reached 10, then start counting once limit is reached.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpsxE.png)

Where overflow is calculated by =IF(HoursToDate>10,HoursAddedOnThatDay,0)

And then IncludedHours = Sum(HoursAdded)-Sum(Overflow)

You can hide choose to hide/move the Overflow table as you like.

**EDIT:
Doing an additional table can be avoided by using the SUMIF function to test whether HoursToDay is less than or equal to your limit. (Note: this won't count any of the hours on the day that crosses your limit)**

[image: Sumif]

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for.  I'll just need to modify these formulas to include offsets.  If I have any more questions I will let you know.  Thanks again so much ! ! !

Comment: @RoelfRossouw I'm glad you found what you needed, but you should really be more clear in what you are asking if you hope to get help.  This accepted answer doesn't meet the expected results from your question

Comment: @Kevin I eventually had the time to test the formula in real life, It works, but as you mentioned, not really to my expectations, but still very helpful, a step in the right direction.  If you want the original spreadsheet to get the bigger picture, I'm sure we can set something up.

Comment: I agree the question should be re-written to describe the situation better, as what you're really looking to do is "How to sum if (before/until) a certain criteria is met". I just realized the answer could be improved with the SUMIF formula since I think that's what you are looking for: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b

Answer (score 0):

[image]Can you set up a separate data validation for each row? So for instance the DT row which has a limit of 2, set the data validation for the that row to Whole Number with a minimum value of 0 and a maximum value of 2. This will only allow an input of a whole number <2 and >0. And then set the maximum value accordingly for each row.

[image]

Comment: Not really what i'm looking yossup, thanx for the reply though.  What you are describing is more in the line of data input limitations, not true ?

Comment: Yes, I must have misunderstood the question..can you please elaborate on what your problem is?

Comment: Ok let me try and explain.  The "limit" of 10 is calculated like this =MIN(10,SUM(C4:I6)).  So what I want to know is, for the green cells, the hours in the table needs to be allocated like this

Of which
OT - 2
DT - 6
PPH - 2

Thats the answer Im looking for, but have no idea how to actually implement this in formulas

Comment: I edited the answer above, 
  
  '=SUM(IF(B2>2,2,B2),IF(C2>2,2,C2),IF(D2>2,2,D2),IF(E2>2,2,E2),IF(F2>2,2,F2),IF(G2>2,2,G2))' then drag it down for all rows; find and replace the 2 in the calculated cell if there is a different limit, so for OT you would find the 2 and replace for 6.

Comment: Thanks for the time you take on this, but what i'm looking for is this.  Which of the 3 categories, hours, makes up 10 hours ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am really not following what the issue is exactly. Maybe if you upload another test example with more detail and what you would like to see that may help.